# How to create and store several instances of a class in order to retrieve them later according to user input

Tags: python

I'm trying to code a score tracking system to create users, which includes usernames, total games played and total games won, as well as a win/loss ratio. I can create the users fine, and when using the `getStats()` subroutine will show the desired attributes, but trying to do so in a different part of the code will cause an error.

```
while cont == "y":
  person = "user" + str(i)
  list.append(person)
  person = User()
  # person.getStats()
  i = i+1
  cont = input("Continue?: ")

print(f"List of users: {list}")
while 1 == 1:
  person = input("Choose a user to view: ")
  person.getStats
  cont2 = input("Continue?: ")
```

I want to be able to choose which user's stats to view after I have created all desired users, however the only way I can get stats to show is by removing `person.getStats()` from the second `while` statement and instead using it in the first `while` statement. Trying to run the code as shown above results in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 35, in <module> person.getStats
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'getStats'
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: `person` is a string, as it was returned by `input`. Why did you expect that it was something else than a string?

Comment: Do not name a variable `list` (or any other name reserved by Python) since it is the name used for the Python `list` type and this could lead to bugs.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention- this code is purely to test an idea I had tested in a separate program before I implemented it into a bigger one. The variable names are not final but instead just a placeholder.

Comment: The first of several problems in your code is that the `User` instances you are creating are never stored in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You should distinguish between person as a string in

```
person = input("Choose a user to view: ")
```

and in

```
person = "user" + str(i)
```

and person as a User class instance in

```
person = User()
```

and in

```
person.getStats
```

Better give them different names

Comment: Thank you for your answer- this code is not a part of anything bigger yet as I wanted to test out an idea before proceeding further. Any names are not final. Is there any way of searching for different objects in the class without resulting in the error?